# displaying structs in an array using enumerator

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, struct, iterator

In an object I have :

```
public IEnumerable<voiture> recup_voitures()
{
    foreach (voiture v in _arrVCollection)
    {
        yield return (v);
    }
}
```

`voiture` being a struct and `_arrVCollection` being an array containing some struct voiture.

In my main class I have :

```
 foreach (CarCollection.voiture o in collection.recup_voitures())
 {
     //some code to display the content of each struct
 }
```

What is happening is that if I have an array of length 5 and only 1 struct voiture in it, it will do the displaying code 5 times instead of only 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean an array of length 5, but only 1 struct voiture in it?

Comment: `voiture[] anArray = new voiture[5];` and then `anArray[0] = new voiture();`

Comment: There's no reason to `yield return` in that method; you can just return `_arrVCollection` directly, as it imlements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are creating array of struct with length, say 5, it means array will contain 5 structs constructed using default constructor.

```
voiture[] arr = new voiture[5];
arr[0] = some_non-default_voiture;
```

In that case your array will contain one non-default `voiture` instance and four default instances.

To get only one `voiture` instance you can create array with length 1, or use `List<T>`:

```
List<voiture> = new List<voiture> { new voiture() };
```

If you really need to deal with array with length 5, consider to use nullable types:

```
voiture?[] _arrVCollection = new voiture?[5];
_arrVCollection[0] = new voiture();
```

And enumerate like this:

```
public IEnumerable<voiture> recup_voitures()
{
    foreach (voiture? v in _arrVCollection)
    {   if (v.HasValue)
            yield return v.Value;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

As Servy mentioned, method `recup_voitures()` can be rewritten with linq:

```
public IEnumerable<voiture> recup_voitures()
{
    return _arrVCollection.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value);
}
```

Comment: Your last method works like a charm! Thank you! Now i'm off to read what are nullable types :)

Comment: Rather than using an iterator block in the second case you can just `return _arrVCollection.Where(v => v.HasValue);`

Comment: @Servy, strongly agree. just wrote it in OP-style.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you get exception.

You can change your code in `recup_voitures` methods if the `voiture` will be class:

```
 public static IEnumerable<voiture> recup_voitures()
        {
            foreach (voiture v in _arrVCollection)
            {
                if (v != null)
                    yield return (v);
            }
        }
```

Comment: They are never null as they are structs

Comment: Ohh... my mistake. I thought that voiture is a class.